# How to find the compass heading in an iOS web app?

Tags: ios, compass-geolocation, heading

Does anyone know how to find the compass heading of an iOS device from within a web app? The new Device Orientation APIs supported in iOS 4.2 only seem to provide relative changes in rotation. Was anyone able to find a workaround to this? (I also get a `null` value for the `coords.heading` property when using `navigator.geolocation`.)

Comment: I have the same problem in iOS 5. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Compass support is available in the devicemotion event through new attributes: webkitCompassHeading and webkitCompassAccuracy. There is also a new event we can subscribe to: compassneedscalibration. This will work only on iPad 2, iPhone 4, 4S and iPod touch last generation.

source: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ios-5-iphone-and-ipad-html5

alternatively: [Access device compass from webb app with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918982/access-device-compass-from-webb-app-with-javascript)