# Access device compass from web app with Javascript

Tags: web-applications, mobile, compass-geolocation

Is it possible to access the compass with Javascript on an iphone/ android device from a web app? Have been looking all over the net for hours I know you can access the accelerometer with

window.ondevicemotion = function(event)

Does anyone know if you can access the information from the compass??

Comment: Things might have changed since [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564219/accessing-iphone-compass-with-javascript) was asked, so I'm not about to close-vote, but it _is_ an otherwise identical question.

Comment: Ya saw that one... however with the release of 4.2 more features were accessible aka accelerometer and gyroscope. http://www.peterfriese.de/apples-updated-developer-license-this-changes-everything-again/

Comment: I read that article which made me wonder if the compass feature was now also available... would be cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iPhone, you can get the compass value like this.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {
    console.log(e.webkitCompassHeading);
}, false);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Android? I wrote a page that works on iOS (Safari and Chrome) but doesn't work on Android.

Comment: I guess there is, but unfortunately, I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be cross platform now, check this [excellent article](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-device-orientation-events) by [Ruadhán O'Donoghue](https://mobiforge.com/author/ruadhan).

For Android, it still uses `window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', ...)` but check for other event properties (`event.alpha` which is compass orientation ; `beta` and `gamma` are also available, which represent the tilting).

Here are the relevant parts (adapted) if the link becomes unavailable:

```
   if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
      window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
        var alpha;
        // Check for iOS property
        if(event.webkitCompassHeading) {
          alpha = event.webkitCompassHeading;
        }
        // non iOS
        else {
          alpha = event.alpha;
          if(!window.chrome) {
            // Assume Android stock
            alpha = alpha-270;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Another usage example is available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rlautan/pen/YPzGjo?editors=0010#0).