# how to direct an arrow on top of compass to point towards specific direction. for e.g. current position to Saudi Arabia

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, compass-geolocation

I am creating an Ionic 4 app with angular and I want to create a compass which would direct towards specific direction. That direction will be presented by an arrow above the compass. So far I have created the compass and compass is working fine and placed an arrow above it. Screen shot of app.[image]

What I know is that i have to calculate an angle from current position to target position.I have used some stack overflow solutions to find angle and use that angle to point arrow to desired location. But unfortunately I can't get my desired angle.

This is the code to determine the angle.

```js
  angleFromCoordinate() {
    let lat1 = this.latCoords
    let lon1 = this.lngCoords
    let lat2 = this.destLat;
    let lon2 = this.destLong;
    var p1 = {
      x: lat1,
      y: lon1
    };

    var p2 = {
      x: lat2,
      y: lon2
    };
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    console.log(angleDeg);
    return angleDeg;
  }
```

I also want the arrow to move along if the device is rotated.
I am rotating my compass with ionic 4's plugin deviceOrientation

```
  this.deviceSubscription = this.deviceOrientation.watchHeading().subscribe(
      (data: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading) => {
        //to torate compass
        this.rotateCompass(data.magneticHeading);
        //to rotate the arrow
        this.rotateArrow(data.magneticHeading);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access device compass from webb app with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918982/access-device-compass-from-webb-app-with-javascript)

Comment: this might also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378435/how-to-access-accelerometer-gyroscope-data-from-javascript

Comment: users/635678/dan-o, this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918982/access-device-compass-from-webb-app-with-javascript  express about device orientation, but i want to get an angle between my location to target location. this is missing

Comment: I have managed to find out the angle between to points using above code in the question, now arrow above the compass is pointing towards desired direction but it is sticky and not moving if the device is rotated . can anyone help me to make the arrow along the device , if device is rotated, the arrow should also rotate

Comment: Hi, I want to implement a compass in my ionic app. Could you please kindly guide me through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working alright. I just want to make it clear if anyone is in search of the solution to this problem that the above mention code for getting the angle from one point to an other point is working fine.
Code to get angle.

```
angleFromCoordinate() {
    let lat1 = this.latCoords
    let lon1 = this.lngCoords
    let lat2 = this.destLat;
    let lon2 = this.destLong;
    var p1 = {
      x: lat1,
      y: lon1
    };

    var p2 = {
      x: lat2,
      y: lon2
    };
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    console.log(angleDeg);
    return angleDeg;
  }
```

This method returns the angle and you can use this angle to point your compass to your desired location.

Comment: How did u make the compass rotate, i am also making a qibla app am just starting am sooo confused

Comment: Can you please explain to me why you are calculating angle between the two point , I thought since you have the coordinates of the destination you will just point your compass towards that angle

Comment: Please can I contact you in any way